# ¿Cómo agrupar filas, contar en una columna y sumar en la otra?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, group-by

Quiero agrupar filas de un archivo csv, contar en una columna y sumar en la otra

Por ejemplo con la siguiente me gustaria aggrupar las lineas sobre la `Commune` hacer columnas de los `winner` con el count y una columna `Swing` con la suma

```
Commune Winner Swing
Paris   PAM    1
Paris   PJD    0
Paris   PAM    1
Paris   UDF    1
Madrid  PAM    0
Madrid  PAM    1
Madrid  PJD    0
```

¿Cómo agrupar filas, contar con una columna en una columna y una suma en la otra?

```
Commune PAM    PJD    UDF    Swing
Paris   3      1      1      3
Madrid  2      1      0      1
```

Hasta ahora intente :

```
g = df.groupby('Commune').Winner
pd.concat([g.apply(list), g.count()], axis=1, keys=['members', 'number'])
```

Pero me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
    members number
Commune     
Paris   [PAM, PJD, PAM, UDF] 4
Madrid  [PAM, PAM, UDF] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer se puede lograr una tabla pivote, mediante [pandas.pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html).

Basicamente indexas por las columnas `Commune` y `Winner`, y agregas los valores de las columnas `Winner` y `Swing` con dos funciones de agregación distintas: *count* y *sum*, respectivamente

De esta manera, se obtiene lo que pides:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# recrear datos
df = pd.DataFrame([['Paris','PAM' ,1],['Paris','PJD' ,0],['Paris','PAM' ,1],['Paris','UDF' ,1],['Madrid','PAM' ,0],['Madrid','PAM' ,1],['Madrid','PJD' ,0],])
df.columns = ['Commune', 'Winner', 'Swing']

pt = pd.pivot_table(
    df, 
    index=['Commune', 'Winner'], 
    values=['Swing', 'Winner'], 
    aggfunc={'Swing': np.sum, 'Winner': 'count'}
)

print(pt)
#                Swing  Winner
#Commune Winner
#Madrid  PAM         1       2
#        PJD         0       1
#Paris   PAM         2       2
#        PJD         0       1
#        UDF         1       1
```